# jmeter : Counter cant reset in same thread

Tags: java, loops, jmeter, counter

Within the "Loop Controller", I want `${counter}` can start from "1" every time when doing "While Controller".

1. Thread Group will run for 5mins
2. Set up infinite to run "Loop Controller"
3. Set up "While Controller" condition as: ${__javaScript(("${List}".indexOf("mostBookmarked") == -1 && ${counter} < 5),)}
4. Disable "mostBookmarked" HTTP, so that it will counter to 5 every while loop

Result now is the first loop it works, but 2nd 3rd loop not working.

Expect result is every while loop it will start to counter from "1".

JMeter result:

[image]

Jmeter thread setup:

[image]

Jmeter "While Controller"  setup:

[image]

Comment: you need to say a whole lot more

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a JSR223 Sampler and input script:
   vars.put("counterValue","1");
2. Create a JSR223 PostProcessor on the request and input script:
   int counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counterValue"))+1;
   vars.put("counterValue",Integer.toString(counter));